# Suppose $M : L$ and $L : K$ are extensions, and that $\alpha \in M$ is algebraic over $K$. Does $[L(\alpha):L]$ always divide $[K(\alpha):K]$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Supposing that $\alpha \in M$ is algebraic over $K$, we then know that $[M(\alpha):L]<\infty$ and $[L(\alpha):K]<\infty$ using the tower law.

How can I find out about $[K(\alpha):K]$ or $[L(\alpha):L]$ from this information?

Comment: you can require that $L/K$ is a normal extension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $K = \mathbb{Q}$, $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$, and $\alpha = \zeta\sqrt[3]2$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Then $[L(\alpha):L] = 2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I'm having trouble rationalizing is how we know that $[L(\alpha):L]=2$?

Comment: Because $L(\alpha) = L(\zeta)$ and $\zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 = 0$.